# How to overwrite variable in python in a function

Tags: python, variables

```
def Change_char_stats():
    Char_dmg = 50
    Char_health = 100
    Char_stat_choice= ''
    print('Current Damage is:',Char_dmg,'and health is:',Char_health,'.')
    Char_stat_choice=input('\nWhat character stat would you like to edit?')

    if Char_stat_choice == '1':
        print('Current damage is',Char_dmg,'.')
        Char_dmg=int(input('Character damage to: '))
        print('Character damage has been changed to',Char_dmg,'.')
        Change_char_stats()

    elif Char_stat_choice == '2':
        print('Current damage is',Char_health,'.')
        Char_health=int(input('Character health to: '))
        print('Character health has been changed to',Char_health,'.')
        Change_char_stats()
    else:
        print('Input invalid.')
        Change_char_stats()

Change_char_stats()
```

So basically I'm working on a simple game for myself on Python, and I'm having an issue with my variables as when I run the program original variables are set to 50 dmg and 100 health, but what I want to do is be able to run the code, change the variables and then have them stay as that. Although I understand why the variables aren't staying as the new values, I have no clue how to over-write them, help would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: You are missing a closing quote `'` on this line `Char_stat_choice=input('\nWhat character stat would you like to edit?)`

Comment: You keep calling `Change_char_stats()` recursively but you don't keep track of any changes done to `Char_health` etc. It might be better to have a character represented as an instance of a class so that you can keep track of changes.

Comment: You should be usign a class and use instances there - but you really should understand better how funcitons workm before defining yur character class. I suggest you take  read on the Python tutorial at https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html

Comment: Do the `if` statements belong inside the `Change_char_stats()` function?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest creating a class to package all of the variables into a single object:

```
def class player_character:
    def __init__(self):
        self.health = 100
        self.dmg = 50
```

Now you create an instance of the class:

```
player = player_character()
```

And change the variables directly:

```
player.health -= 10
```

Alternatively, you can add functions to the class:

```
def class player_character:
    def __init__(self):
        self.health = 100
        self.dmg = 50

    def hit(self, dmg):
        self.health -= dmg
```

Now you can call the function on an object:

```
player.hit(10)
```

Classes are incredibly powerful and great tools for organizing code. They allow you to treat a lot of data as a single entity. I strongly encourage you to learn more about them and object oriented programming in general.

Answer (score 0):

Place the variables outside function body and make them accessible within usng global keyword:

```
somevar = 5

def foobar(x):
    global somevar
    somevar = x

print somevar
foobar(6)
print somevar
```

Comment: This would be interesting in a multiplayer game :) There's no reason to use globals here.

Comment: Well, there is in a sense it does properly answer what the OP asked. I would not downvote this answer, as it is "correct". But I won't upvote it either, unless it explains what are the issues with this design, and offers a better one.